# gunicorn server with gevent worker start workers sequentially when cpu bound process is used

Tags: python, flask, optimization, gunicorn, gevent

I am using `gunicorn` with `gevent` worker. When I start server and `init` has some `cpu bound` process than it's showing linear growth in time to start the app even though I have `16 core` and my system is doing nothing except starting this server.

I can't show the application where I am seeing this behavior but have created a sample app to simulate the same.

```
# Server.py
import gevent.monkey

gevent.monkey.patch_all()

import os

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Response, send_from_directory
from flask_cors import CORS
from core import Core

app = Flask(__name__)


cors = CORS(app)

@app.route("/process_query", methods=["POST"])
def process_query() -> Response:
    return "", 200


def create_app() -> Flask:
    """
    Creates a Flask based app
    """
    try:
        app.dm = Core()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error here", e)
        return None

    print("Creating app")
    return app
```

```
#  My CPU bound app object
from typing import List, Dict, Any
from time import time, sleep
import os


class Core:

    def __init__(self, config_path: str = None) -> None:

        print(f"{os.getpid()} Init start {time()}")
        start = time()
        for i in range(1,1000000000):
            pass
        sleep(1)
        end = time()
        print(f"{os.getpid()} Init done {time()} : {end - start}")


    def get_response(self, req: Dict[str, Any]) -> Dict[str, Any]:

        start = time()
        try:
            return "{}"

        except Exception as e:
            raise e
```

```
# Start command I am using 
gunicorn 'agent_server:create_app()' --chdir ./ --worker-class=gevent -w 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:5006 --timeout 900
```

To repro Change `-w 3`value to different values like `-w 1` or `-w 16` depending in number of cors you've. It will show linear growth in time taken to start the app.

Any idea what's going on as `gevent` should be async worker and each worker start on different cors.

I found this link https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/design.html

> The asynchronous workers available are based on Greenlets (via Eventlet and Gevent). Greenlets are an implementation of cooperative multi-threading for Python. In general, an application should be able to make use of these worker classes with no changes

This says gevent uses multi-threading and python's multi threading is not truly parallel. So is that the issue.